# How to simplify the expression with sigma notation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (n-i+1)(2i-1)^2= \frac{n(2n^3+4n^2+n-1)}{6}$$ how does this work? Could anybody show the details.

Comment: Could you answer it?

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you edited your question after Santosh Linkha answered.

Staying in line with what Santosh Linkha wrote, start expanding the summand $$(n-i+1)(2i-1)^2=(n+1)- (4 n+5)i+ (4 n+8)i^2-4 i^3$$ and now $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (n-i+1)(2i-1)^2= (n+1)\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1-(4n+5)\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i+(4n+8)\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2-4\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^3$$  and use Faulhaber's formulas as suggested by Lucian. After simplifications, you will arrive to the result $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (n-i+1)(2i-1)^2= \frac{n(2n^3+4n^2+n-1)}{6}$$

Comment: Is there a better way than  F's formula? I mean to under it I need to know the Bernoulli numbers. But then I have no idea what exhaustion and integrals are.

Comment: The summations of $i^k$ are almost classical identities. Just remember the first formulas given at the beginning of the Wikipedia page (Examples). For the time being, forget Bernoulli numbers.

Answer (score 1):

First simplify the inner terms, then sum each term individually. The following relations will be helpful.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n 1 &= n \\ 
\sum_{i=1}^n i &=  \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\\ 
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 &= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
\end{align*}

I suppose you know the first two relations. You will find the proof of the third relation [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/69756) or just on [google](https://www.google.com/). Also the [online calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B%28n%20-%20i%20%2b%201%29%20%282%20i%20-%201%29,%20%7Bi,%201,%20n%7D%5D) says, your expression is wrong. check your question again.

Comment: Now it's right. Forgot the second power

Comment: Don't you first have to multiply it out. Then I don't how it is helpful.